# symfony2 project for web and mobile app

Tags: symfony

I want to build an application for web and also for android. The application will have a database, and users should be able to login and perform some actions.

In Symfony2 documentation you can find all the information about how to create a web site, also there is information about how to create a symfony2 REST API.

However it is not clear for me, how to create a symfony2 web site that consumes a symfony2 REST API, and also (as it is a web service) be able to use the same REST API to consume from my android app

Any idea will be really appreciated

I am new using symfony2

Thanks

Comment: After a while, I Bootstraped my project. And for Android side I have created a small project pointing to my site. That way I did not require to create any Web service. It is a small project and for now it is going well.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your REST API easily with [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle). There is a nice tutorial on the subject [here](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/).

In building your website, you have some options.

- You can query the database directly in your controllers.
- You can query your REST API in your controllers using [cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).
- You can query your REST API in your views use jQuery or just AJAX.